# Heroku deploying sqlite3 database path error

Tags: python, sqlite, heroku, sqlite3-python

When I deploy my app with sqlite3 database, Heroku gives me this error:

[Error traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgeTv.png)

I am sure that problem is not with path. Code works correct on my computer every time when I create or open database.

[Path for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNqfh.png)

All works correct only if instead:

```
self.conn = conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATABASE_PATH)
```

I write:

```
self.conn = conn = sqlite3.connect("guilds")
```

Another paths don't work, but in this case database guilds creates in folder with main file

Is it Heroku troubles?

Comment: Unless it's a read-only database, you can't use SQLite with Heroku. See the duplicates. (Some old answers will say that Heroku's filesystem is read-only. That's no longer true, but it _is_ [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). All changes will be lost frequently 
and unpredictably.)

Comment: @ChrisGPTwasonstrike but that's strange that if i write just "guilds", sqlite3 works.

Comment: Only temporarily. Forget about the path, even if you get it "working"' it won't work. See the dupes.